# How to mask sensitive information while logging in spring integration framework

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have requirement to mask sensitive information while logging. We are using wire-tap provided by integration framework for logging and we have many interfaces already designed which logs using wire-tap. We are currently using spring boot 2.1 and spring integration.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that all your integration flows log via the mentioned global single `wire-tap`.

This one is just a start from another integration flow anyway: it is not just for a channel and logger on it. You really can build a wire-tapped flow any complexity.

My point is that you can add a `transformer` before `logging-channel-adapter` and mask a `payload` and/or `headers` any required way. The logger will receive already masked data.

Another way is to use some masking functionality in the `log-expression`. You may call here some bean for masking or a `static` utility: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#logging-channel-adapter

Comment: How can i invoke the static methods which take the payload as input from the wiretap.

Comment: Wire-tap does nothing but just sends a message to the configured channel. If you talk about a `log-expression` in the `logging-channel-adapter`, then you need to study what is SpEL and how can we call `static` methods from there: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-types

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a fancy approach, but I ended up implementing some sort of "error message filter" to mask headers in case the sensitive one is present (this can be extended to multiple header names, but this gives the idea):

```java
@Component
public class ErrorMessageFilter {

    private static final String SENSITIVE_HEADER_NAME = "sensitive_header";

    public Throwable filterErrorMessage(Throwable payload) {
        if (payload instanceof MessagingException) {
            Message<?> failedMessage = ((MessagingException) payload).getFailedMessage();
            if (failedMessage != null && failedMessage.getHeaders().containsKey(SENSITIVE_HEADER_NAME)) {
                MessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = new MessageHeaderAccessor(failedMessage);
                headerAccessor.setHeader(SENSITIVE_HEADER_NAME, "XXX");
                return new MessagingException(withPayload(failedMessage.getPayload()).setHeaders(headerAccessor)
                        .build());
            }
        }
        return payload;
    }

}
```

Then, in the `@Configuration` class, added a way to wire my filter with Spring Integration's `LoggingHandler`:

```java
    @Autowired
    public void setLoggingHandlerLogExpression(LoggingHandler loggingHandler, ErrorMessageFilter messageFilter) {
        loggingHandler.setLogExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>((m) -> {
            if (m instanceof ErrorMessage) {
                return messageFilter.filterErrorMessage(((ErrorMessage) m).getPayload());
            }
            return m.getPayload();
        }));
    }
```

This also gave me the flexibility to reuse my filter in other components where I handle error messages (e.g.: send error notifications to Zabbix, etc.).

P.S.: sorry about all the `instanceof` and `ifs`, but at certain layer dirty code has to start.